# position (X, Y coordinates) update on page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to capture the position of click on an image (marked as x for end users). But on window resize the 'X' position changes. Is something I am missing in my code, how can i maintain the position in portrait and landscape modes

```
<script>
$("#_img").on("click",function(event){
   var X = event.pageX-5, Y = event.pageY-5;
   $("#marker").css({
     "left":X,
     "right":Y 
   }).show();
});
</script>

<img id="_img" src="car.png" width="550px" height="168px"/>
<div id="_mrk" style="display:none;">x</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle ?? May be you need to mention the unit(`"left : X+'px'"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update position of 'x' everytime window resized or orientation changed and image should be in perentage instead of pixels

```js
var width = 0;
    var height = 0;

    $("#_img").on("click", function(event) {
      var X = event.pageX,
        Y = event.pageY;
      $("#_mrk").css({
        "left": X,
        "top": Y
      }).show();
      width = $("#_img").width();
      height = $("#_img").height();
    });

    function getNewValue(posValue, oldImgPos, newImgPos) {
      return posValue * (newImgPos / oldImgPos);
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
      var newx = getNewValue($('#_mrk').offset().left, width, $("#_img").width());
      $("#_mrk").css("left", newx);

      var newy = getNewValue($('#_mrk').offset().top, height, $("#_img").height());
      $("#_mrk").css("top", newy);
      width = $("#_img").width();
      height = $("#_img").height();
    });
```

```css
 #_mrk {
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    #_img {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<img id="_img" src="http://clipartion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/colorable-car-line-art-free-clip-art.png" width="550px" height="168px" />
  <div id="_mrk" style="display:none;">x</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save value of document width when `img` is clicked. Add event listener to `resize` event and change `X` and `Y` values when it fired:

```
var X, Y, doc_width, a_ratio;

$("#_img").on("click", function(event){
   X = event.pageX-5;
   Y = event.pageY-5;
   doc_width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
   a_ratio = $(this).width()/$(this).height();
   move_mark(X, Y);   
});

$(window).on("resize", function(){
   var x = X + (document.documentElement.clientWidth - doc_width);
   var y = Y + (x - X)/a_ratio;
   move_mark(x, y);
})

function move_mark(X,Y){
    $("#marker").css({
     "left":X,
     "right":Y 
   }).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentage instead of pixels to support all sizes.
First of all make sure the container of the img and the marker is position relative, and the marker is position absolute.

Then, when clicking you will need to calculate the X and Y within the image, and then based on that calculate percentage.

```
var img = $("#_img");
img.on("click", function(event){
    var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    var left = 'calc(' + ((x / img.width()) * 100) + '% - 5px)';
    var right = 'calc(' + ((y / img.height()) * 100) + '% - 5px)';
    $("#marker").css({
        "left": left,
        "right": right 
    }).show();
});
```